# themes for windows form application in c#

Tags: c#

Where can i find theme support for my c# windows applications.? Is there any theme maker or ready for use themes

Answer (score 3):

WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) themes looks much better than normal windows forms.

But if you are still looking for windows form app themes you can try out [Fancy Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FancyNetForms.aspx) By [Nedim Sabic](http://www.codeproject.com/Members/Nedim-Sabic).

Comment: That looks really promising. Have you used it personally on any projects?

Answer (score 2):

We are using the (commercial) products from [DevExpress.com](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/).

They support theming, have great support and were the best tool I could find. Using it for approx. 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Forms.Net application you can use visualstyler.

For more information https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7937dfc6-b216-421a-97e8-6483c5727914